# How to Configure the Route in Codeigniter?

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing

I am facing an issue with the URL below.

```
http://domain.com/profile/_username
```

I don't want to show the "profile" portion in the URL. How do I show the URL in the below format using htaccess?

```
http://domain.com/_username
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if _username is a method name then you can't access a method which is starting with _ 
(under score is used to make private a method in codeigniter)